# SImples Java Multiplex chat server

Tags: java, sockets, server, chat, channel

I'm trying to do a simple chat in java using a multiplex server but I'm having a little problem: I can't seem to be able to iterate through the socket channel and relay a message to all clients connected to the server.

Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/ZaXzsRpA

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server
{
  static private Selector selector;
  // A pre-allocated buffer for the received data
  static private final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 16384 );

  // Decoder for incoming text -- assume UTF-8
  static private final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
  static private final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();


  static public void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    // Parse port from command line
    int port = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );

    try {
      // Instead of creating a ServerSocket, create a ServerSocketChannel
      ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();

      // Set it to non-blocking, so we can use select
      ssc.configureBlocking( false );

      // Get the Socket connected to this channel, and bind it to the
      // listening port
      ServerSocket ss = ssc.socket();
      InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress( port );
      ss.bind( isa );

      // Create a new Selector for selecting
      selector = Selector.open();

      // Register the ServerSocketChannel, so we can listen for incoming
      // connections
      ssc.register( selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT );
      System.out.println( "Listening on port "+port );

      while (true) {
        // See if we've had any activity -- either an incoming connection,
        // or incoming data on an existing connection
        int num = selector.select();

        // If we don't have any activity, loop around and wait again
        if (num == 0) {
          continue;
        }

        // Get the keys corresponding to the activity that has been
        // detected, and process them one by one
        Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
          // Get a key representing one of bits of I/O activity
          SelectionKey key = it.next();

          // What kind of activity is it?
          if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) ==
            SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT) {

            // It's an incoming connection.  Register this socket with
            // the Selector so we can listen for input on it
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println( "Got connection from "+s );

            // Make sure to make it non-blocking, so we can use a selector
            // on it.
            SocketChannel sc = s.getChannel();
            sc.configureBlocking( false );

            // Register it with the selector, for reading
            sc.register( selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ );

          } else if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) ==
            SelectionKey.OP_READ) {

            SocketChannel sc = null;

            try {

              // It's incoming data on a connection -- process it

              sc = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
              boolean ok = processInput( sc );

              // If the connection is dead, remove it from the selector
              // and close it
              if (!ok) {
                key.cancel();

                Socket s = null;
                try {
                  s = sc.socket();
                  System.out.println( "Closing connection to "+s );
                  s.close();
                } catch( IOException ie ) {
                  System.err.println( "Error closing socket "+s+": "+ie );
                }
              }

            } catch( IOException ie ) {

              // On exception, remove this channel from the selector
              key.cancel();

              try {
                sc.close();
              } catch( IOException ie2 ) { System.out.println( ie2 ); }

              System.out.println( "Closed "+sc );
            }
          }
        }

        // We remove the selected keys, because we've dealt with them.
        keys.clear();
      }
    } catch( IOException ie ) {
      System.err.println( ie );
    }
  }


  // Just read the message from the socket and send it to stdout
  static private boolean processInput( SocketChannel sc ) throws IOException {
        // Read the message to the buffer
        buffer.clear();
        sc.read( buffer );
        buffer.flip();

        // If no data, close the connection
        if (buffer.limit()==0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Decode and print the message to stdout
        String message = decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
        System.out.println("RECEIVED: "+ message);
        buffer.flip();
        //InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress( port );
        //ss.bind( isa );

      // Create a new Selector for selecting
      //selector = Selector.open();

        Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("One for each connect");
            // Get a key representing one of bits of I/O activity
            SelectionKey key = it.next();
            if(key.isAcceptable())
                continue;
            SocketChannel scAux = (SocketChannel)key.channel();

            scAux.write(buffer);
            buffer.rewind();
        }

        buffer.clear();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Anyone able to give me some feedback?